# Using CDate() in a SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got a Database which have Text formatted Dates, now i need to filter specific Date ranges.

This Query works for me:

```
SELECT CDate(field) AS df
FROM table
WHERE CDate(field)=Date();
```

Sadly i didn't found how i can use a SQLAlchemy Query like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy_access as sa_a

# …

tbl = sa.Table("so71529087", sa.MetaData(), sa.Column("field", sa_a.DateTime))
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

qry = sa.select(sa.func.CDate(tbl.c.field).label("df")).where(
    sa.func.CDate(tbl.c.field) == sa.text("Date()")
)
print(qry)
"""
SELECT CDate(so71529087.field) AS df 
FROM so71529087 
WHERE CDate(so71529087.field) = Date()
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(qry).all()
```

Comment: Thanks, "func.CDate()" its what i was looking for :) For my Example it looks like: session.query(Table_Class).filter(func.CDate(Table_Class.Str_Field) >= datetime.today()).all()